# Remove Section from PHP Includes

Tags: php, include, indexing

I have a site that uses PHP includes. There are snippets of code in the header and footer includes (one in each) that I want to use on every page except the homepage (index.php). Obviously, I can take them out of the includes and put them into every page except the homepage, but I was wondering if I can have them in the includes and then remove them from the homepage with some code.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you concidered using a controller? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !='index.php')
   #do your code here that you want on every page EXCEPT index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can check if `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` matches your homepage, and if so, not execute the code within your includes.  Modify the path `/home.php` to whatever your home page is called.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/home.php") !== FALSE) {
  // execute code that shouldn't go onto the home page
}
```